# Copy 3rd column from tab-delimited TXT file?

Tags: batch-file

In a batch file, how do I copy the 3rd column from my 280 tab-delimited TXT files into a new set of TXT files.
Format example from textfile `001.txt`

```
apple   green   nice
banana  yellow  good
cherry  red healthy
```

The new output file `001-output.txt` should look like this:

```
nice
good
healthy
```

This needs to be done for the 280 files.

Comment: What characters are used in the txt files?  Only alpha characters?

Comment: vot VVFIN <unknown>  alpha TAB alpha+special TAB alpha+special

Comment: Did you answer my question?  I don't know what you wrote there.

Comment: characters are alpha A-Za-z plus a few special characters, e.g. <>.$

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pressing the TAB key in notepad.exe for example, or typing ALT+009 As `delims`

when you're writing your code

```
@echo off&cls

for %%x in (*.txt) do (
 for /f "tokens=3 delims=[Here type ALT+009]" %%a in ('type "%%x"') do echo %%a>>%%~nx_output.txt)
```

and it will work

And like @Foxidrive said :

```
@echo off&cls

for %%x in (*.txt) do (
 for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('type "%%x"') do echo %%a>>%%~nx_output.txt)
```

will work to.

Or you can create a variable containing the TAB char with this method :

http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3857

Comment: The default delims are space and TAB - you don't need to specify it. TAB was broken in earlier Windows (W2K?) but it works in modern Windows.

Comment: You're right @Foxidrive, but it can be a method to make a difference with others files who don't have this TAB structure in the directory.

Comment: Your code makes it more difficult for the newbie.  Why would you want to do that?

Comment: In case who you just want to get the text in file having a TAB structure and not the others. But that's a very specific case, you're right.

Comment: how do i know from the code that it's the 3rd column of text i want to extract?

Comment: with the tokens (`"tokens=3"`) if you want the fifth column use : `"tokens=5"`

Comment: I typed in the following in the command line: `@echo off&cls 
for %%x in (*.txt) do ( for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('type "%%x"') do echo %%a>>%%~nx_output.txt)`  It says "The syntax of the command is incorrect." How am I supposed to hit enter (use the carriage return) in the DOS command prompt?

Comment: You have to put that in a `.bat` file I.e `Test.bat`. Then put this `test.bat` in your working directory and run it the CMD prompt.